# Possible to not allow jQuery sortable moving item within the same list, but ok with other list?

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui

I have two connected sortable lists: `list_b` and `list_a`. What I am trying to accomplish is to allow visible placeholders only in `list_b`. `list_a` is only used to pull from so I don't want placeholders when dragged within `list_a` (at least visible ones that take space), but I want `list_b` to show placeholders when they are dragged from `list_a`.

Basically:

- `list_a` item to `list_b` = show placeholder in `list_b`
- `list_b` item to `list_b` = show placeholder in `list_b`
- `list_a` item to `list_a` = do not show placeholder, or use a
  placeholder that is styled display:none; in `list_a`
- `list_b` item to `list_a` = do not show placeholder, or use a
  placeholder that is styled display:none; in `list_a`

jQuery:

```
$( "#list_a, #list_b" ).sortable({
connectWith: ".connected_sortable",
start: function (e, ui) {
  //Closest I can get but now both lists don't show placeholders.
  if(ui.item.context.parentNode.id != 'destination_list')
    ui.placeholder.hide();
},
}).disableSelection();
```

HTML:

```
<ul id="list_a" class="connected_sortable">
  <li value="0">test text</li>
  <li value="1">test text</li>
</ul>

<ul id="list_b" class="connected_sortable">
  <li value="2">test text</li>
</ul>
```

Is there a way to do this outside of combining the jQuery draggable plugin with the sortable plugin? I do not want to go that route because I've encountered some jQuery bugs when using both plugins together.

Comment: and u don't need moving from b to a ?

Comment: Yep, I don't need to go back from b to a

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[js Fiddle example for my answer](http://jsfiddle.net/A4Xvw/)

You can make list_a connect to list_b but not connect list_b to list_a. That way dragging list_b items to list_a wont be possible. example:

```
$( "#list_a" ).sortable({
    connectWith: "#list_b"
});
$( "#list_b" ).sortable({
    placeholder: "placeholder"
});

$( "#list_a, #list_b" ).disableSelection();
```

But if you just want to hide placeholder then you could do this with css:

```
#list_a .placeholder {display:none}
```